# What does it mean when the main method throws an exception?

Tags: java, exception

I'm reviewing a midterm I did in preparation for my final exam tomorrow morning. I got this question wrong, but there's no correct answer pointed out, and I neglected to ask the prof about it.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
```

Which of the following statements about this code is correct?

1. The main method is designed to catch and handle all types of exceptions.
2. The main method is designed to catch and handle the `FileNotFoundException`.
3. The main method should simply terminate if the `FileNotFoundException` occurs.
4. The main method should simply terminate if any exception occurs.

I had chosen the second option.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Answer is number 4,

> 4.- The main method should simply terminate if any exception occurs.

The throws clause only states that the method throws a checked FileNotFoundException and the calling method should catch or rethrow it. If a non-checked exception is thrown (and not catch) in the main method, it will also terminate.

Check this test:

```
public class ExceptionThrownTest {

    @Test
    public void testingExceptions() {

        try {
            ExceptionThrownTest.main(new String[] {});
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            assertTrue(e instanceof RuntimeException);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        dangerousMethod();

        // Won't be executed because RuntimeException thrown
        unreachableMethod();

    }

    private static void dangerousMethod() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    private static void unreachableMethod() {
        System.out.println("Won't execute");
    }
}
```

As you can see, if I throw a `RuntimeException` the method will terminate even if the exception thrown is not a `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: umm, but the question is regarding `public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
` signature, not in general

Comment: Well, test it, if you throw a checked exception other than the `FileNotFoundException` it won't compile. Otherwise, if the method throws a unchecked exception, then It will simple end propagating the unchecked exception.

Comment: What do you think about my answer?

Comment: @ElderMael Could you kindly explain what does `@Test` keyword or the symbol do? I tried to google with no luck, and I don't know what it is described as either.

Comment: Ah Alright, Thanks @ElderMael. I tried this annotation at a regular code and was throwing error.

Comment: Perhaps Effective Java's Item 59, `Item 59: Avoid unnecessary use of checked exceptions
`, comes into play: `If the programmer using the API can do no better, an unchecked exception would be more appropriate.` In other words, perhaps an unchecked exception is more appropriate in the case of `main throws XException...`.

Comment: @ElderMael is the FileNotFoundException considered to be catched in main in this example?

Comment: Why do you need the testingExceptions() method?

Comment: @rimalonfire it was there to show it using a unit test. Just an example.

Comment: Option 4 logically implies option 3, so there is no way that it can be correct without 3 being correct as well. If X happens if any exception occurs, then X also happens if `FileNotFoundException` occurs, because `FileNotFoundException` is an exception.

Comment: Wrong, Number 3 is correct.

Answer (score 12):

Dude, a little late, but answer is Number 3.

Number 1 is false because it is not handling FileNotFoundException

Number 2 is false for the same reason.

Number 3 is true. If a FileNotFoundException is thrown, the main method will terminate.

Number 4 is false. It would not terminate in case of ANY exception. It would terminate only in case of unchecked exception or FileNotFoundException. If there are not other checked exceptions declared in the 'throws' clause, it means they are being handled within the method.

Comment: This answer is clearly wrong. why isn't there any comments or down votes on this? A method which only `throws` without any `try-catch` statement will ***not*** handle the exceptions.

Comment: I think the purpose of this exercise is to imagine what's inside the main method. I agree it leaves room for ambiguity and assumptions. But, since it throws a FileNotFoundException I assume any other Checked Exceptions are being handled (with a try-catch). Also I assume it is not handling unchecked exceptions.

Comment: @user3437460 You are mistaken.  You do not need a `try` block in a function to have the function throw an exception.  If the function which is listed as throwing the exception calls *another* function which throws that exception, the exception will simply be passed up the stack.

Answer (score 4):

The main method is not catching any exceptions, instead it handles the `FileNotFoundException` by throwing it to the source which invoked the main method.

The system runtime launches the JVM classes, one specific class among the JVM classes invokes the main method.

The handling for the main method's `throws` is at the mercy of the JVM classes in that case.

- You can read about it in the [Java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/execution.html#44459) provided by Oracle.
- Additionally you can view the source code for some of the JVMs available out there, going that path though takes you away to other programming languages,[OpenJdk](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/).

I thought of sharing my small humbled research crust in that topic, hope it helps curious ones :)

Comment: "Java language specification" link is broken. This is currently working link to the [Java 11 Execution chapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-12.html).

And here is a link to a more detailed explanation of [how JVM handles exceptions thrown by the main method](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/257174/how-does-the-jvm-handle-an-exception-thrown-by-the-main-method).

Answer (score 4):

I agree with some other answers that the correct answer to the question is option 3. Option 4 says:

> 4. The main method should simply terminate if any exception occurs.

Note the "any" in this option. Here's an example of code in which an exception occurs, but `main()` does not terminate:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try {
        methodThatThrowsACheckedException();
    } catch (SomeCheckedException e) {
        // do something to handle this exception
    }
}
```

In this code an exception occurs, but the method does not terminate, as it's been setup to handle this exception. If the exception were an uncaught `UncheckedException`, then the method would terminate, of course. The point of option 4, though, is that any counter-example invalidates it, since it says "any" exception occurs.

Option 3, however, limits this termination to only occur when the exception in the method's signature is thrown:

> 3. The main method should simply terminate if the `FileNotFoundException` occurs.

The reason option 3 makes more sense is because code like the following does not make sense in practice:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try {
        methodThatThrowsFileNotFoundException();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // do something to handle this exception
    }
}
```

It doesn't make much sense to declare that a method throws an exception, but catch that exception in the method (unless, perhaps, you re-throw it after doing something, in which case option 3 still holds, as the method terminates eventually).

Answer (score 0):

With only the declaration of `main()`, it is impossible to say which answer is objectively correct.  Any of the statements could be true, depending on the definition of the method.

> 1. The main method is designed to catch and handle all types of exceptions.
> 2. The main method is designed to catch and handle the `FileNotFoundException`.

Both of the above statements are true of the following:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    while (true) {
        try {
            doSomething();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

The declared exception is never thrown by `main()`, but that is not an error; just pointless and misleading.

> 3. The main method should simply terminate if the `FileNotFoundException` occurs.
> 4. The main method should simply terminate if any exception occurs.

Both of the above statements are true of the following:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try {
        doSomething();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return;
    }
}
```

---

Of course, we can guess at the intention of the question based on what a decent and reasonable programmer might intend to communicate with this method signature.  Which would be that they intend for the method to throw `FileNotFoundException`, and necessarily handle other checked `Exception`s.  We can also reasonably assume that "handle" does not just mean "process", but specifically that it will not (re-)throw such an exception.

These assumptions immediately rule out #1 and #2.

The remaining question is whether "simply terminate" includes throwing an exception, or only an explicit `return`/`System.exit()`.  In the former case, both of #3 and #4 could still be true:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try {
        doSomething();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        throw fnfe;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return;
    }
}
```

In the latter case, neither #3 nor #4 can be true while also satisfying the assumption that `main()` will throw `FileNotFoundException`.

---

In sum, the options are not worded well.  If I had to pick an answer, it would be #3 based on the logic of MartinV's answer.  My assumption would be that the word "should" in #3 was an unfortunate choice by the professor, and that something like "may" would have been a better option.  It would also have been a good idea to use more precise language than "simply terminate" (and, arguably, "handle").

Comment: The word "occurs" is not particularly precise either. I would say an exception that is thrown and caught internally has nevertheless "occurred", but will have no effect on main's behavior.