# Exception thrown in method

Tags: java, exception

```
public class X { 

      public void foo() throws Exception{ 
             System.out.print("hi "); 
             throw new Exception(); 
} 

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {

                X c = new X();
                  c.foo();
    }    
}
```

As in my foo() method I am throwing Exception and propagating the Exception by using throws. In my main() method I am again propagating my Exception.
When I compile it works fine.

My question is: why don't I need to handle this `throw new Exception()`? Who is taking care of this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does it mean when the main method throws an exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773340/what-does-it-mean-when-the-main-method-throws-an-exception)

Comment: There is a thread default exception handler that catches the exception.  It's default action (if you don't override it) is to terminate the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

It will be thrown to the err console as your
main method declares "throws Exception".
Remove this and it won't compile anymore.

Comment: but i want to know why is this? is my thrown exception is handled by the same method foo()?

Answer (score 0):

Every thread has a [handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) for uncaught exceptions—exceptions that terminate the thread. The default exception handler invokes [`printStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29) on the `Throwable` that terminates the thread, unless the error is an instance of [`ThreadDeath`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadDeath.html) You can change this behavior on a particular thread by [setting a custom handler,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) for a group of threads by [extending `ThreadGroup`,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#uncaughtException%28java.lang.Thread,%20java.lang.Throwable%29) or for all threads by [installing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) a default handler.