# How to fix IOException

Tags: java

I tried several file path for this but still get IOException even though the file exists
Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] letters = {"a", "b"};
        Object ob = new object(letters);
        ob.training(new File("C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/train.txt"));
        ob.classify(new File("C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/data.txt"), new File("C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/classify.txt"));
    }
```

I used throws statement in my training and classify methods but it would still ask me to use throws statement at the main method and when I do that it wouldn't run. Or it would run but simply does not pass the compiling test of a programme called CodeGrade. Could anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Is `Object ob = new object` really what you want (note the capital ‘O’) - maybe that’s your compiler error.

Comment: Whatis the exceptions stacktrace? (and since the two methods `training` and `classify` are involved, maybe include those too?)

Comment: the `File(String path)` constructor can throw an IOException, so you must either catch that exception (with a `try/catch` construct) if you want to do something about it, or declare that your `main` method may throw it (by adding `throws IOException` to its signature. With that done, you need to tell us what other compile error you're getting or why your code doesn't pass its tests, we can't guess with that little code

Answer (score 1):

File operation can throw IOException which are checked, i. e. must be handled explicitly. You can declare main method in such way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
```

Then your code should compile.

Answer (score 1):

try to look here

[What does it mean when the main method throws an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773340/what-does-it-mean-when-the-main-method-throws-an-exception)

but if you use windows maybe this is your sol:

```
new File("C://Users//Dell//Desktop//train.txt"))
```